# WSO2 EI and NODE JS

Tags: node.js, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I currently have some rest api in my backend consumed by the front, now they asked me to integrate them through the ESB of WSO2 Enterprise integration.
I have read the WSO2 EI documentation but I cannot find the solution to my problem.
If someone could help me find documentation on how to do it, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: At this moment I only have the api rest working directly with consumers, and I don't know where to start to implement the ESB, so I ask for guidance to do so

Answer (score 0):

Based on your wording I get the idea you disagree? :) 
First you need to understand the goal of the ESB, which is (amongst others)

- connecting 3th party applications
- providing a layer of abstraction (offering throttling, security and access control)

In your case your existing API is working fine and you are not bothering with any of the extra features yet so I'd suggest you create a 'pass-through' API which just forwards the message to the API backend and sends the response back.

Normally you would use the Developer Studio tooling to create a project, but in this case I'd suggest you start out with logging in on the WSO2 carbon console (https://hostthatrunstheESB:9443/carbon) and click 'APIs->Add API' in the menu.
An example would be:

```
<api context="/francosapi" name="ExampleAPI">
    <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/test">
        <inSequence>
          <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address url="http://yourapiurl.local" />
             </endpoint>
           </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
          <send/>
        </outSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

Comment: I think there is an error in the closing of the keys (double </endpoint> and </send>), try to solve it but without success

Comment: Ah, you are correct, the first 'send' has no closing tag. Edited.

Comment: Excuse me for the delay to answer you.
When trying to save the api an error appears. "An API must contain at least one resource definition"

Comment: hmm odd, how about now?